# How do I extract the contents of a CPT's custom field for all posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, wp-cli

I need to generate a CSV report with information that is stored into a few custom fields of a custom post type. How do I list just the content of these custom fields, for all — or a subset — of these custom post types?

(I'm trying to use wp-cli to achieve this, because it's an extremely powerful and versatile tool that never failed me before. Sorry if I'm approaching it as an "[X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"!)

For now all I got is `wp post list --post_type=<MYCPT> --posts_per_page=1` to get me the most recent post, and then `wp post meta list <ID>` with the ID returned in the previous command.

This lists me **all** the custom fields for a **single** custom post. What I need, however, is the content of **just a few** custom fields, for **all** custom posts of this type.

I suppose I can write a bash script to iterate through everything and grep just the custom fields I want, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted by piping wp-cli with xargs and grep, like this:

```
wp post list --post_type=CPTNAME --field=ID | xargs -n 1 wp post meta list --format=csv | grep -E "^[[:digit:]]*,(CUSTOMFIELD1|CUSTOMFIELD2|...|CUSTOMFIELDN)" >> file.csv
```

This is, however, **extremely slow**, taking more than 30 minutes for 10 thousand CPTs.

I think a direct SQL query would be much, much more efficient.